# Trying to use twisted on OSX

Tags: python, macos, twisted, twisted.internet

I recently found the Twisted python library and was trying to set it up with a test script.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Pong(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 5\r\n\r\nPong!\r\n")
        self.transport.loseConnection()

# Start the reactor
factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = Pong
reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
reactor.run()
```

When i run the above (I am using python 2.7.9 btw) in Terminal, I get an error. The last line of the error is below. If you need the rest, I can post it as well.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_NO_TLSv1_1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OP_NO_TLSv1_1` is an attribute in pyOpenSSL. This means your version of pyOpenSSL is too old. `pip install -U pyopenssl` or `pip install twisted[tls]` should resolve this, but I'd highly recommend doing all of this in a virtual environment if you aren't already.

Comment: What exactly is a virtual environment? How do I set one up?

Comment: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ can get you started. There are dozens of other guides out there for various ways to make it easier to use, etc.

Comment: Thank you. The virtual environment made everything work fine and I didn't even need to use the upgrade commands.